# nginx - redirect domain to a different domain and specific path with hash

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

I'm trying to go from `mynewdomain.com` to `mytenantsite.com/tenant.html#store/home`.

I have tried variations of:

```
server {
listen 80;

    server_name *.mynewdomain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://mytenantsite.com/tenant.html#store/home;
}
```

and

```
server {
listen 80;

    server_name *.mynewdomain.com;
    rewrite ^/$ mytenantsite.com/tenant.html#store/home last;
}
```

I have tried permanent for last as well, but both send to `mytenantsite.com`, and not to `mytenantsite.com/tenant.html#store/home`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Lose the wildcard.

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return       301 https://www.newdomain.com/whatever/path#location;
}
```